# Apache Flink and cluster deployment (Standalone/YARN/Mesos)

Tags: cluster-computing, hadoop-yarn, apache-flink, mesos

I browsed Flink documentation but I don't find a deep comparison between Flink's features in standalone/YARN/Mesos deployment except technical guides to setup them.

I'm a newbie in cluster computing so I had never used YARN or Mesos. I've just learned something about their functionalities on google. Anyway I would like to understand how can I choose which deployment mode I have to use. 
Apparently it seems that with YARN or Mesos I will have automatic failure recovery but if this is true... which are the reason to setup Flink without them?

I would to develop a cluster where a stream computing is performed, I use Kafka as source and Cassandra as sink of data so the cluster is just a real-time processor which doesn't store data: they just pass through it. 
There are no pre-existing cluster, I have research interest so I would to understand better setup to fit my purpose. My load actually is not heavy (about 35millions messages/day - 35 GB/day) but however I would to setup a well-formed cluster able to handle future big loads.

Can you explain me how to choose between these cluster setup or provide me some links to learn it?

P.S. I have no pre-existing cluster or infrastructure, I will deploy a real cluster for my thesis.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If streaming is only use cases . You might be interested in https://www.confluent.io/blog/introducing-kafka-streams-stream-processing-made-simple/ which can help with streaming use case with creating extra cluster on YARN . You can use kafka connect to put data in cassandra .  https://github.com/tuplejump/kafka-connect-cassandra

Comment: Excuse me but your is not an appropriate answer to my question. I discarded Kafka Streams in favour of Flink.

Comment: I have not used Mesos so can explain on that part . But we are running are our flink streaming and batch jobs using YARN in production .

Few Benefits of using Flink wih YARN  are :

1. You can easily work with Hadoop/HDFS/HBase(if needed) with flink (Main reason we are using YARN with HDFS )
2. The “as needed” allocation of containers allows for different profiles of containers (CPU / memory) to be used for different operators
3. Failure detection and restart of that process is done by YARN.

Comment: 1. Yarn Cluster Setup :http://arturmkrtchyan.com/how-to-setup-multi-node-hadoop-2-yarn-cluster   2. https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.2/setup/yarn_setup.html#yarn-setup